# how to temporarily store data in redux or redux saga on different phases of a process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

(This is mostly a question on how to implement it)

I am new to react and trying to implement the logic below using the current configuration of the project `Hooks + Redux + Saga.`

React `16.9`

## LOGIC FLOW

```
* The user is authenticated already.
* These two steps need to happen on the same URL but the UI displayed on different pages.
* No dependency allowed.

STEP 1:
-Each student has one form they need to fill out.
-The form has two fields: course and teacher. (value has to be typed)
-Once the two fields are filled out press button next.  

STEP2:
-The fields typed by the student will be displayed on the top of the page
-On this page, the student has a list of materials they can pick and add to the list to attend the course. 
-After choosing the material, the student can click Save
-Now when the student clicks Save, there is a page redirect to the home page.
```

My question is what would be the best way to implement the functionality:

- that allows the student on STEP1 to click the `Next button` (Nothing is save yet), have the ability to show the fields entered from the form on the top of the next page
- then only after pressing `save` on STEP 2, be able to save all the informations from STEP 1 and STEP 2 pages.

It's mostly that kind of state management that i am trying to understand.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Possible Idea:
1. You will have a component named **Steps** which contain child Components **Step1** and **Step2**.
2. The **Steps** component will have a state of type `{currentStep,step1Data,step2Data}`
3. Based on the value of **currentStep** you will render **Step1** or **Step2** component which will show the forms.
4. when student will fill form in **Step1** or **Step2** the data will be stored in **step1Data** or **step2Data** of state of **Steps** component.
5. After save **step1Data** and **step2Data** will be saved on redux(or a server call haeppen).

Thanks

Comment: Thats a good idea, thanks - will a `switch case` make sense to use for step 2 and 3?